# Linphone OSx msx264 encryption VGA takes 97% CPU, why?

Tags: c, macos, ffmpeg, x264, linphone

I have problem and today don't know how to fix it or even from where to start.

I have Linphone application that uses msx264 plugin.

All stuff I run on OSx and my ffmpeg version installed from `port` , I didn't using selfupdate for port

```
bash-3.2# port installed ffmpeg-devel

The following ports are currently installed:
 ffmpeg-devel @20130205_0+gpl2
 ffmpeg-devel @20130328_0 (active)
 ffmpeg-devel @20130328_0+gpl2
```

So I compiled and build msx264, no errors.

Now I try to send video over CIP resolution VGA (640x480) and get huge delay 8-9 seconds, **even self-view I see in big delay**.

when I configure CIF (352x288), all seems fine.

It's really strange that self-view camera has delay 4-5 sec.

So from logs during the session I found that **msx264 plugin takes 97% CPU**

On PC (windows 7) the same code runs fine, even HD I don't see any problems.

What is the problem should be?

```
warning: Video MSTicker: We are late of 32146 miliseconds.
message: Filter MSRtpRecv is not scheduled; nothing to do.
message: ===========================================================
message:              AUDIO SESSION'S RTP STATISTICS                
message: -----------------------------------------------------------
message: sent                                          2344 packets
message:                                             403168 bytes  
message: received                                      2038 packets
message:                                             350536 bytes  
message: incoming delivered to the app               325080 bytes  
message: lost                                             0 packets
message: received too late                              123 packets
message: bad formatted                                    0 packets
message: discarded (queue overflow)                      17 packets
message: ===========================================================
message: ms_filter_unlink: MSAuRead:0x7fb5a34955b0,0-->MSResample:0x7fb5aa917820,0
message: ms_filter_unlink: MSResample:0x7fb5aa917820,0-->MSSpeexEC:0x7fb5a34f6d20,1
message: ms_filter_unlink: MSSpeexEC:0x7fb5a34f6d20,1-->MSVolume:0x7fb5a3493450,0
message: ms_filter_unlink: MSVolume:0x7fb5a3493450,0-->MSTee:0x7fb5a3498e40,0
message: ms_filter_unlink: MSTee:0x7fb5a3498e40,0-->MSUlawEnc:0x7fb5a3499410,0
message: ms_filter_unlink: MSUlawEnc:0x7fb5a3499410,0-->MSRtpSend:0x7fb5aa910ba0,0
message: ms_filter_unlink: MSRtpRecv:0x7fb5a3400170,0-->MSUlawDec:0x7fb5a34933c0,0
message: ms_filter_unlink: MSUlawDec:0x7fb5a34933c0,0-->MSGenericPLC:0x7fb5aa91b040,0
message: ms_filter_unlink: MSGenericPLC:0x7fb5aa91b040,0-->MSDtmfGen:0x7fb5a6585f00,0
message: ms_filter_unlink: MSDtmfGen:0x7fb5a6585f00,0-->MSVolume:0x7fb5aa917790,0
message: ms_filter_unlink: MSVolume:0x7fb5aa917790,0-->MSTee:0x7fb5aa914fc0,0
message: ms_filter_unlink: MSTee:0x7fb5aa914fc0,0-->MSEqualizer:0x7fb5a3498f50,0
message: ms_filter_unlink: MSEqualizer:0x7fb5a3498f50,0-->MSSpeexEC:0x7fb5a34f6d20,0
message: ms_filter_unlink: MSSpeexEC:0x7fb5a34f6d20,0-->MSResample:0x7fb5aa9178b0,0
message: ms_filter_unlink: MSResample:0x7fb5aa9178b0,0-->MSAuWrite:0x7fb5a3499380,0
message: ms_filter_unlink: MSTee:0x7fb5a3498e40,1-->MSAudioMixer:0x7fb5aa914df0,0
message: ms_filter_unlink: MSTee:0x7fb5aa914fc0,1-->MSAudioMixer:0x7fb5aa914df0,1
message: ms_filter_unlink: MSAudioMixer:0x7fb5aa914df0,0-->MSFileRec:0x7fb5aa911020,0
message: Audio MSTicker thread exiting
message: ===========================================================
message:                   FILTER USAGE STATISTICS                  
message: Name                Count     Time/tick (ms)      CPU Usage
message: -----------------------------------------------------------
message: MSX264Enc           321       138.147             97.1677   
message: MSResample          8076      0.0550274           0.97085   
message: MSSpeexEC           4302      0.0873765           0.821276  
message: MSH264Dec           291       0.880267            0.561463  
message: MSRtpSend           6174      0.012353            0.166623  
message: MSRtpRecv           6174      0.0115132           0.155295  
message: MSOSXGLDisplay      375       0.0376117           0.0308912 
message: MSAudioMixer        4695      0.00249638          0.0256072 
message: MSV4m               1480      0.00740446          0.0239537 
message: MSUlawEnc           4038      0.0019542           0.0172411 
message: MSTee               6540      0.000698976         0.00998688
message: MSAuRead            4695      0.00095017          0.0097466 
message: MSUlawDec           1890      0.00205553          0.00849059
message: MSVolume            5928      0.000633159         0.00820007
message: MSFileRec           4695      0.000722743         0.00741371
message: MSDtmfGen           4695      0.0005              0.00512887
message: MSGenericPLC        4695      0.000429514         0.00440585
message: MSAuWrite           4038      0.000364199         0.00321319
message: MSEqualizer         1890      0.000250661         0.00103538
message: MSSizeConv          322       0.00104334          0.000736128
message: MSJpegWriter        290       0.000694158         0.00044124
message: MSPixConv           322       0.000405573         0.000286151
message: MSFilePlayer        0         0                   0         
message: MSVoidSink          0         0                   0         
message: ===========================================================
warning: Video MSTicker: We are late of 32256 miliseconds.
message: v4m video device closed.
message: Filter MSRtpRecv is not scheduled; nothing to do.
message: ===========================================================
message:              VIDEO SESSION'S RTP STATISTICS                
message: -----------------------------------------------------------
message: sent                                          1311 packets
message:                                            1517528 bytes  
message: received                                      1783 packets
message:                                            1049010 bytes  
message: incoming delivered to the app               986868 bytes  
message: lost                                             0 packets
message: received too late                                0 packets
message: bad formatted                                    0 packets
message: discarded (queue overflow)                       0 packets
message: ===========================================================
```

In addition the application shows me delay status, from logs:

```
message:: Dialog [0x7fb5a7634940]: now updated by transaction [0x7fb5aa9685d0].
warning: Video MSTicker: We are late of 20415 miliseconds.
warning: Video MSTicker: We are late of 20564 miliseconds.
message:: A SPS is being sent.
message:: A PPS is being sent.
warning: Video MSTicker: We are late of 20609 miliseconds.
warning: Video MSTicker: We are late of 20636 miliseconds.
warning: Video MSTicker: We are late of 20694 miliseconds.
warning: Video MSTicker: We are late of 20784 miliseconds.
warning: Video MSTicker: We are late of 20894 miliseconds.
warning: Video MSTicker: We are late of 21016 miliseconds.
warning: echo canceller: we are accumulating too much reference signal, need to throw out 1216 samples
message:: audio_stream_iterate(): local statistics available
Local's current jitter buffer size:77.440002 ms
message:: bandwidth usage: audio=[d=80.1,u=80.1] video=[d=305.3,u=441.8] kbit/sec
message:: Thread processing load: audio=2.135499    video=1268.186768
warning: Video MSTicker: We are late of 21134 miliseconds.
warning: Video MSTicker: We are late of 21256 miliseconds.
warning: Video MSTicker: We are late of 21382 miliseconds.
warning: Video MSTicker: We are late of 21506 miliseconds.
warning: Video MSTicker: We are late of 21638 miliseconds.
warning: Video MSTicker: We are late of 21781 miliseconds.
warning: Video MSTicker: We are late of 21921 miliseconds.
message:: bandwidth usage: audio=[d=81.6,u=80.0] video=[d=271.9,u=185.5] kbit/sec
message:: Thread processing load: audio=1.971647    video=1342.125000
warning: Video MSTicker: We are late of 22068 miliseconds.
message:: audio_stream_iterate(): remote statistics available
remote's interarrival jitter=68
remote's lost packets percentage since last report=0.390625
round trip time=0.258850 seconds
warning: Video MSTicker: We are late of 22216 miliseconds.
```

Please, help me to find the problem.

Thanks,

this is a msx264 git repository: `git clone git://git.linphone.org/msx264.git`

Comment: I don't see a programming question here ?

Comment: right, I didn't post C code, I just try to understand why for OSx msx264 takes 97% CPU only for VGA and >. I used different ffmpeg versions but get the same version. Linphone is open source project written on pure C

Comment: I don't think anyone can answer this question without looking at code or without being intimate with the code base in question, so it's probably not a good fit for SO. Maybe there's a mailing list or forum somewhere for people who work with this code, where you might be more likely to get help ? Failing that you could try using a profiler (e.g. Instruments on OS X) to find out where the code is spending most if its time.

Comment: Thanks, I have mail list, as you see Linphone has private tag in stack overflow. I think its not program problem but OS of MAC, maybe someone meet the same CPU leak ...